# mplayer timestamp not disappearing

Tags: linux, video, streaming, mplayer, linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint 8 64bit with Google Chrome Unstable (same problem with beta).

When a video is playing, the time elapsed and total time stay on the screen:

[image: mplayer timestamp not disappearing]

Is there a way to make this disappear? I've tried all kinds of preferences, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>o</kbd> to cycle through the timestamp display modes. From the manpage:

```
o
  Toggle OSD states: none / seek / seek + timer / seek + timer + total time.
```

Comment: what character is that? It's not reacting to either o (as in omg) or 0  (as in 1-1)

Comment: That's a lowercase 'o' as in zomg. Not sure what chrome does to mplayer, but I guess you should probably have the mouse over the movie "box".

Comment: got it. had to open it in fullscreen mode for it to respond to the keyboard.